# What is regex to exclude + and allow only numericals

Tags: html, reactjs, json, regex

I've tried
^[0-9]*$
And
^\d*$
But they're allowing +,++

When tried ^[^+]*$ it is still allowing +

Comment: Those don't normally match `+` or `++`, though. Maybe a variable was changed before you tried to use it? Show more code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `.match(/\-?\d+(\.\d+)?/gi)` maybe help

Answer (score -1):

This will allow you to have numeric value excluding '+'
^[0-9][^+]+$

Regex 101 link-
https://regex101.com/r/ptrSs1/1

Comment: This also allows non-numeric values like `0abc`